# Comparing Columns in different Workbooks, editing rows that match

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two tables of varying length in different worksheets. A 'master' and a 'dependent'.  I am trying to compare a column (A) of Sheet1(Master) and if it matches Column(A) of Sheet2(Dependant) copy the row from Sheet2 to Sheet1.

I have found a snippet of code that looks promising, but I can't figure out how to achieve my desired result.  I am not the greatest at creating and manipulating arrays yet.

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s=ss.getSheetByName("Master")
  var lr=s.getLastRow()
  var lookup = s.getRange(3,1,lr,5).getValues();
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Sheet_id');
  var s2=ss2.getSheetByName("Dependent") 
  var lr1=s2.getLastRow()
  var range = s2.getRange(3,1,lr1,5 ).getValues();
  var lookupRange = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < lookup.length; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j < range.length; j++) {
     var  test=lookup[i][0]
         if(lookup[i][0]==range[j][0]){
           lookupRange.push([range[j][0],range[j][1],lookup[i] 
[0],lookup[i][1],]);                      
     }}}
   s.getRange(3,1,lookupRange.length,2).setValues(lookupRange); 
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to overwrite your data in Master Sheet?

Comment: Yes.  The sheets are being used as a type of communication board.    In essence, the Master sheet is a consolidation of all work orders, the Dependent is one specific work center.  If the manager of the workcenter makes an edit, I need it to appear on the Master sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var MSsId='';
var mshName='Sheet1';
var DSsId='';
var dshName='Sheet2';

function findMatchesAndCopy() {
  var mss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(MSsId);
  var msh=mss.getSheetByName(mshName)
  var mrg=msh.getRange(3,1,msh.getLastRow()-2,5);
  var mvA=mrg.getValues();
  var dss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(DSsId);
  var dsh=dss.getSheetByName(dshName);
  var drg=dsh.getRange(3,1,dsh.getLastRow()-2,5);
  var dvA=drg.getValues();
  var mmA=mvA.map(function(r){return(r[0])});
  for(var i=0;i<dvA.length;i++) {
    var idx=mmA.indexOf(dvA[i][0]);
    if(idx>-1){
      mvA[idx]=dvA[i];
    }
  }
  mrg.setValues(mvA);                
}
```

This what the master spreadsheet looks like after running the script:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I am making my need clear.  The "MASTER" sheet and "DEPENDENT" Sheet will have the same number of column headers.  I would like the script to search Column A of the master for a Match on the Dependent.  If it finds one, I will need it to then copy that line of the Dependent and copy it to the line of the Master where it found the match.  Example:  if (Master!A20) matches (Dependent!A4) copy (Dependant!A4:E4) to (Master!A20:E20).   Regardless if the outcome, I appreciate your help.

Comment: I'd like to have a link to a copy of your spreadsheets that has all of the private information removed.

Comment: [Master Sheet] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c7HsKf27PDzvfz4azfRWextXxb5Vl1Djx3TYp9UkoVs/edit#gid=0)

Comment: [Dependent Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1csTKgthrUpZoYMf-d-8y54h9N-tecsNZftLoaOF8u-s/edit#gid=169140663)

Comment: Dependent should be public now.  On the Master the only sheet is FIRST, on Dependant, SECOND.

Comment: Your question says that the sheets are Sheet1 for the Master Spreadsheet and Sheet2 for the Dependent Spreadsheet and your comment above says the Master Spreadsheet sheet name is Master and the Dependent  Spreadsheet sheet name is Dependent.  So how about fixing your question and making your example sheets match the question.

Comment: Thanks for your edits.  I did script in a separate spreadsheet than either the master or the dependent so I opened them both by id.

Comment: Incredible!   Works like a dream!  I even duplicated it to a "Dependent 2" sheet and got the other rows to fill in!   Now to combine this with the other script you helped me with the other day to highlight the changes.